# Some properties on my response is NULL and can't track request over Fiddler

Tags: c#, api, rest, postman, fiddler

Let me provide some information where the problem arises. I have REST API developed using .NET Core 2.2. It is actually a proxy which calls an .asmx WebService on another server. I am using Postman to make requests. When I run the API from Visual Studio 2019 I get a proper response, but when I call it from the server I get a response but some properties are missing and return null. I am sure that I have the exact same code because I have just published.

Then I run the same code from the Visual Studio 2019 installed on the server. Again, when I run it from the Visual Studio everything is OK, but calling it on the IIS causes the same problem and some property values return null, although they actually are not.

Another weird point is that, again when running calling the API from the Visual Studio Run, I observe on Fiddler that the request is gone to the original server and the response is properly returned. But then I call it over IIS there is no traffic displayed on Fiddler but I still get the response, yet again some properties are set to NULL.

Anyone encountered such a problem or can suggest either a solution or a walk through to investigate the situation?

Comment: Check the headers on first request to see if they are the same in all situations.  When you update your code old cookies may exist and the request is using parameters from the old request so make sure when you are doing updates you remove the old cookies before testing.

Comment: I have checked the headers and they are identical except the request time. Hoe can I clear cookies under an IIS?

Comment: You can also do a call to a Web Service from Postman. Can you try that and see the response, isolating it from your API?

Comment: I usually use a browser and go into advance internet settings and delete cookies.